# Java Concurrency in app server

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, concurrency, hashmap

I have a small web application with CRUD operations. For the data, I can't use a db, so I must store it in a map or similar data structure. Based on the requirement, I need two maps to store and access the data, and I have to make sure they are in sync with each other. 
Now, the question, what is the preferred way to make crud operations on the two maps on in a multi threaded environment making sure they are in consistent state. Is there a better approach or pattern to avoid locking and synchronization?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there has to be some synchronization involved. You can try the following approach.
First of all use a `ConcurrentHashMap` for both of your maps. Then encapsulate both your maps in an object that will have synchronized methods to ensure your data is in a consistent state. The following is an example:

```
public class ParentMap {
   private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map1 = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> map2 = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

   public synchronized void add(Object objectToAdd) {
      // Add to map1 
      // Add to map2
   }

   public synchronized void update(String key, Object object) {
      // Update the object based on the key on both maps (following the rules of your application)
   }

   public synchronized void delete(String key) {
      // Delete in both maps following the rules of your application
   }

   public Object get(String key) {
      // Use the rules of your application to read
   }
}
```

Ensure that there is only one `ParentMap` object in your application. You may use the Singleton Pattern for this.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the reply. That is also what I am thinking of; however, I am wondering if there is an alternative lock free approach ?

Comment: I don't think there is an approach without locking otherwise you will end up with inconsistent states. Even when you use a database, there is some locking involved behind the scenes. Using mysql as an RDBM example, it has table level locking or row level locking. For nosql databases such as mongodb, it has collection level locking or document level locking.